# what is the best way to get all pair shortest path in very large scale weighted and directed graph?

Tags: python, algorithm, shortest-path, floyd-warshall

I'm trying to find all pair shortest path in very large scale graph. I tried floyd-warshall but it is not fast enough because of very large scale of the graph. Number of vertices is more than 100k. Maybe it will take more than a week... Actually I don't need all of the paths. I only need the longest one.

Comment: Is the graph acyclic? Otherwise you'll run into infinite longest path (repeat the cycle ad infinitum)

Comment: Yes it is. You can assume there is no cycle.

Comment: Finding the shortest path is in a DAG has complexity ∅(V+E). Code and algorithm available all over on the net.

Comment: You say you want the shortest path in the title, but in the end of the description you want the longest one?

Comment: @DaniMesejo He wants the longest of all those shortest paths.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to implement the all-pair-shortest-path variant of [Hagerup](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;?doi=10.1.1.381.2907&rep=rep1&type=pdf). The time bound of `O(nm + n^2 log log n)` might be much better than Floyd–Warshalls `O(n^3)` depending on how many edges your graphs have.

You might also be able to set up Neo4j and use it to calculate that path:
https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/alpha-algorithms/all-pairs-shortest-path/#algorithm-all-pairs-shortest-path-sample

```
CALL gds.alpha.allShortestPaths.stream({
  nodeProjection: 'Loc',
  relationshipProjection: {
    ROAD: {
      type: 'ROAD',
      properties: 'cost'
    }
  },
  relationshipWeightProperty: 'cost'
})
```

I don't know that, but depending on the syntax you might be able to select only specific paths from the stream.

Comment: If there are no cycles, the edges are `n - 1` (assuming `n` are the number of nodes), right?

Comment: @DaniMesejo if your graph is undirected, yes